# Does using FULLTEXT in MySQL require for me to use a different syntax in PHP to retrieve the results?

Tags: php, mysql, full-text-search, prepared-statement, fulltext-index

Here's my code:

```
$terminosBuscados = 'Vender la porteria'

$x = $conectarDB->prepare(" 
    SELECT DISTINCT 
    titulo,
    FROM_UNIXTIME(fecha, '%d-%m-%Y') AS fecha,
    cuerpo,
    tipoContenido,
    autor
    FROM searchIndex 
    WHERE match(titulo) 
    AGAINST (' ? ' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
    ORDER BY contenidoID DESC
    ");
$x->bindParam(1, $terminosBuscados);
$x->execute();
$y = $x->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

This is showing no results at all (`$y` returns `null`), when trying the query itself in phpMyAdmin does work and show results.

I've just added a FULLTEXT index into the table and adapted my working code to use that index.

Comment: Did you keep the space surrounding the searched item in phpMyAdmin? (`' ? '`)

Comment: Are you getting any results when **not** doing prepared statements? `" ... AGAINST (' $terminosBuscados ' IN BOOLEAN MODE) ... "`

Comment: Yes, the only difference was the I repleaced the question mark with the words.

Comment: Why do you have `'` around the `?` in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For mysql ' ? ' is a string, and will not be used as palce holfer.

If you need the spaces use `CONCAT(' ',?,' ')`

```
$x = $conectarDB->prepare(" 
    SELECT DISTINCT 
    titulo,
    FROM_UNIXTIME(fecha, '%d-%m-%Y') AS fecha,
    cuerpo,
    tipoContenido,
    autor
    FROM searchIndex 
    WHERE match(titulo) 
    AGAINST (CONCAT(' ',?,' ') IN BOOLEAN MODE)
    ORDER BY contenidoID DESC
    ");
$x->bindParam(1, $terminosBuscados);
$x->execute();
$y = $x->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```